# Exporting BeautifulSoup/Python loop to CSV or txt file

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Not exactly sure how this should look, but I want this code to be written into a csv file. I've tried making taking the entire output and doing output.to_csv('output.csv') but I can't seem to get that to work.

```
import csv ;import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

url_list = ['https://basketball.realgm.com/player/player/Summary/2',
            'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/player/Summary/1']

for url in url_list:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    player = soup.find_all('div', class_='wrapper clearfix container')[0]

    playerprofile = re.sub(
        r'\n\s*\n', r'\n', player.get_text().strip(), flags=re.M)

    output = playerprofile + "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using output.to_csv() which is the function of pandas but in your code you have imported csv module. To write in csv using csv module use this code below your output variable

```
with open('output.csv', 'a') as output_file:
  output_file = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',')
  output_file.writerow([output])
```

Feel free to ask me in case of any question.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, you need to open a file descriptor and write in append mode to it.
file = open('output.csv' , 'a' )
for URL in url_list:
...
file.write(output)